# How to update stock quantity

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

**VB.NET**

Well, I'm using Access as DB containing five tables viz. Vendors, PurOrder, Customers, SalesOrder, Stock.

Vendors: VendorID(PK), Name, Contact, Phone, Address.

PurOrder: POID(PK), Items, Quantity, Rate, Total

Customers: CustID(PK), Name, Phone, Address

SalesOrder: SOID(PK), Items, Quantity, Rate, Total

Stock: SItemID(PK), Items, Quantity, Rate, Total
I'm using the Database Wizard in VB.NET Express. I do not need to code for that. I click on Data Sourses > add the Database > Drag that to my Purchase and Sales form and that automaticaly creates the ADD, DELETE, & SAVE as well as Navigation buttons as toolstrip. and furthermore I drag the Purchase order table (for example) to the form in Datagrid mode and that's it! Now, I can SAVE, DELETE, & ADD records to my database as Purchases.

Well I am able to enter and save/update purchase and sales vouchers and retrieve the reports Customer/Vendor ID-wise and print that.

The only problem I have is that I don't know what to do in order to automatically update the sock quantity when purchase or sale is made.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In many other mainstream database software, they support Trigger, which achieves your goal (automatic update the purchase count). Consider using other database software, as MS Access's performance is not so good.

To answer your question, you have to do an extra query to update the value.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a QUICK reply. CAN YOU PLEASE ASSIST ME IF I USE SQL SERVER ??

Comment: Please follow the instruction here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: Seems a very good link but I can not use that as I'm not a code guru like you. I need HELP!!

Comment: Well Shivan,I can ADD, DELETE and Save records through the buttons automatically added by the Data Source wizard. I just want that on clicking a button named 'Receive Stock' just bellow in the purchase invoice automatically adds (updates) the items in my Stock table. And I can already save, delete and add the purchase invoice. Please need your HELP!!

Comment: You'd probably need to re-write the database connection & query part if you change to MS SQL server